# Prefetch queryset when related_name="+"

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

Is it possible without related name (`related_name="+"`) to prefetch objects on the target instance? Sure I know it's not a problem with the related name, but I'm not really sure if it's possible without it.

Here is the example code:

```py
from django.db import models


class Parent(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)


class Child(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey(to=Parent, related_name="+", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)


Parent.objects.all().prefetch_related('child_set')
```

Maybe it's possible using the `Prefetch(lookup, queryset=None, to_attr=None)` object, because it takes the queryset in the argument list?

Comment: What kind of problem you're experiencing here? Did you tried and faced an error or you're asking "what if" alike question?

Comment: @Charnel The problem is that, related name is used in the queryset lookups, so when related name is unset, it cannot be used in the queryset lookup like `Parent.objects.filter(child__[insert attribute]=...)`. The same behavior applies to prefetches.

Comment: You can still use `_set` sufix like `fieldname_set` if you haven't specified related name.

Comment: I have `related_name="+"` it's in the question name and in the sample code.

Comment: What's the point of `related_name="+"` if you want to access the backwards relation anyway?

Comment: It's because of separation of concerns between multiple apps. But that's not the point here.

Comment: @KryštofŘeháček The point is `related_name="+"` means you don't want the backwards relation. Later you say you still want it, is this not a contradiction and does it not mean that you need to reconsider that you really want to use `related_name="+"`?

Comment: I think from the architectural perspective it's fine, I need it just for the optimisation by prefetching the resources instead of making hundreds of sql queries.

Answer (score 0):

Looked through the code a bit and found this [line](https://github.com/django/django/blob/45bef6706ae7436b5c2c503018b21ff70b2e6728/django/db/models/query.py#L1797):

```
rel_obj_descriptor = getattr(instance.__class__, through_attr, None)
```

Here `instance` is the model instance, and `through_attr` is the field name of related instance to be fetched. This line basically tries to get a related descriptor to perform the prefetch query. In your case `rel_obj_descriptor` would contain `None`.
To answer your question no it is not possible at least for a Foreign Key, there may be some hack for Many to Many relationships as Django appears to use some internal descriptors for them.
I would advice you to simply not set `related_name="+"` since you want to use the backwards relation here. You say *"It's because of separation of concerns between multiple apps"* but that does not make much sense. Don't we set a foreign key to the user model for various other models anyway and still use the related name? Does the point of separation of concerns arise there(the user model is in a separate app)?

Answer (score -3):

try

```
parent = Parent.objects.get(id=pk)
parent.child_set.all()
```

I don't know if having related_name = '+' prevents this situation, but if you never define related_name, you can definitely use this method.

Comment: Yes, but `related_name="+"` is required.

Comment: did you try this ??```parent = Parent.objects.get(id=pk)
parent.child_set.all()```

Comment: Please read the question again and the discussion below the question.